# Weird functionality when using ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript

Tags: vb.net

I'm having this weird problem using the  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript. Basically what I'm trying to accomplish when I click a button control, it goes back to the server, checks to see if any errors, and **what I want to happen** is that if there are any errors, want to use a popup box. The button control is inside an update panel. I thought the easiest way to accomplish this was to use a javascript alert box. So I finally got it working but when the alert box comes up it messes up my menu control until the alert box is going then its ok. Its kinda of hard to explain so I have insert a image to show you guys whats going on once the button is clicked. I dont know how to fix or whats going on, if someone could point me into the right direction. Also he my code im using. [image]

```
 Protected Sub btnPlan_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnPlan.Click

 'Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
  sb.Append("<script language='javascript'>")
  sb.Append("alert(' No data in the database  ');")
  sb.Append("</script>")

    If (Not ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("JSScript")) Then
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(UpdatePanel5, Me.GetType(), "JSScript", sb.toString(), True)
    End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your suggestion. I skinned this a different way and got it to work the way I wanted. What i did was put the message in a hidden textbox and used jquery to ensure that the page was already load then alert the message if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to use RegisterClientScriptBlock:

```
Protected Overrides Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender as Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
     MyBase.Page_Load(sender, e)

     Try
         If Not ScriptManager.IsInAsyncPostBack Then
              Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "AlertScript", "<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>function YourAlert(){alert(' No data in the database  ');}</script>")
         EndIf
     Catch ex As Exception
     End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you checking to ensure that your script manager isn't posting back? I added some detail to the answer. The Try-Catch is so you can put a breakpoint in to look at what's going on at a higher resolution.

Comment: When checking with breakpoints, I see that its going into the if statement but the alert message no longer appears.

Comment: Hmm, after looking at msdn's site, I think I needed to recommend a better suggestion for the key parameter (e.g. the edit). It might not be able to resolve Guid so it fails.